# Qt populate context menu with menubar

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on implementing a **right-click context menu** on a `QWidget`. I was wondering if there is a way to make this menu *inherit*, *copy* or in some way *show* the elements in the `MainWindow`'s `ui->menubar`.

Comment: I don't know any way that's even more direct, but you can take the `QAction`s from the main menu and add them to the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer now that properly does what I want. Could be better, but is fairly efficient and condensed:

```
void MainWindow::customContextMenu(const QPoint &posa) {
    QMenu contextMenu;
    QPoint globalPos = ui->widget->mapToGlobal(posa);
    QList<QMenu*> list = ui->menubar->findChildren<QMenu*>();
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        contextMenu.addMenu(list.at(i));
    }
    contextMenu.exec(globalPos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt Documentation -> Menus Example: [In particular, implementing a right-click context menu on a QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html)
The main part of the code:

```
void MainWindow::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QMenu menu(this);
    menu.addAction(cutAct);
    menu.addAction(copyAct);
    menu.addAction(pasteAct);
    menu.exec(event->globalPos());
}
```